# Laravel Improve Getting Data From Database

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code in getting the data from the database to pass to review page. But the problem here is it will took 1min 30secs or 2-3mins before the loading will be finished.

```
 $province = $this->getProvince(); // Get Province Library
 $cityPostalCode =  $this->getCityPostalCode($id = null);  // Get City Library
 $occupations = $this->getOccupations(); // Get Province Library
 $schoolname = $this->getSchoolname(); // Get Schoolname Library

 return view('pages.frontend.review', compact('data',
   'province', 
   'cityPostalCode', 
   'occupation', 
   'schoolname') 
 );
```

This is my code in getting each data in database

**For province**

```
protected function getProvince(){
  $province = Db::table('address_library')->select('province', 
  'province_code')->distinct()->get(); return $province; 
}
```

**For City Postal Code**

```
protected function getCityPostalCode($id){

  if(!empty($id)){

   $cityPostalCode = Db::table('address_library')
                   ->select('province_code','city','postal_code')
                   ->where('province_code','=',$id)
                   ->distinct('postal_code')
                   ->get(); }   
  else {  
        $cityPostalCode = Db::table('address_library')
        ->select('province_code','city','postal_code')
        ->distinct('postal_code')
        ->get();   
    }

    return $cityPostalCode; 
}
```

**For Occupations**

```
protected function getOccupations(){

   $occupation_library = Db::table('occupation_library')
                 ->select('id',  'title')
                 ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                 ->distinct()
                 ->get(); 

   return $occupation_library; 
}
```

**For Schoolname**

```
 protected function getSchoolname(){

    $schoolname = Db::table('schoolname_library')
                  ->select('code', 'name')
                  ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                  ->get(); 

    return $schoolname;

 }
```

It will took 1min 30secs or 2mins before loading the page

Comment: how many records are there in your database?

Comment: If you can modify the tables of the database, add indices to the columns like there is no tomorrow.

Comment: in postal code. thousands of datas.

Comment: If you have too many records maybe you could use `paginate()`

Comment: but it will be used for select field

Comment: If you are inserting thousands of data in your select field maybe you should try to use [this](https://laraget.com/blog/select2-and-laravel-ajax-autocomplete) helps me a lot

Comment: Thanks, @ShobiPP, my eyes were bleeding.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used in posting with codes. Thanks @Shobi

Comment: its, cool @LordGrim

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a lot of data you are better of with using `chunk` approach, like mentioned in the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#chunking-results).

If it's still unclear I will post an example

Comment: Then how will you get the rest of the datas?

Comment: You use `chunk` only on tables where you know you will have `thousands of results`, if you wanna further speed up the page load, you can always load this data through ajax, where `chunk` really comes into play